# Does /var/spool/mail/user ever get cleared?

Tags: linux, email, unix, cron

I have a crontab task running every 5 minutes. It writes an output (result of the .sh file run by the crontab) to the /var/spool/mail/user. Should I be worried that this spooler will build up and slow down the system over time? Do these entries ever get cleared out? Are they only temporary? If possible, can I disable it.

Comment: This is a question about what it takes to program safely on Unix.  It is on topic for SO.

Comment: I hope the output written by the crontab task is formatted as a valid e-mail message.  If it isn't, you're messing up the user's e-mail inbox.

Answer (score 4):

The messages stay there until the user whose mail it is reads and deletes the mail.  That might be years later (I kid you not!).

- No, the directory is not cleared out by anything.
- Yes, you need to be worried about the problem of filling up your disk with unread email.

Comment: A possible solution might be to forward your mail to some email address that you really are reading. Another would be to redirect in your `crontab` the *stdout* & *stderr* outputs. If they are redirected or empty, `crond` won't send any email.

Comment: To send the email to another email address in your crontab edit it and add a line similar to this: MAILTO=user@example.com

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the /var/spool/mail/user directory remain until the user deletes the mail. You may wish to install a script that runs via cron to remove files older than a certain date, and tweak this as you monitor your system.

Comment: Don't do this without notifying your users well in advance.  I would consider an automated script that deletes my e-mail to be hostile.

Answer (score -2):

I added this line to crontab to my user root:

```
* */2 * * * /bin/su - root -c cat/dev/null > /var/spool/mail/root
```

So every 2 hours, it is cleaned for that specific user (root).

Comment: That schedule doesn't do what you think it does, and there's no need to `su` to `root` if you're already running as `root`.